# Slicer increment button in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to create a button that would increase the value of a slicer by 1 increment (or the next value)?
Can I somehow contribute to make this a feature?

I tried parameters, but that solution does not seem to fit the problem.
I saw that button bookmarks can refer to specific settings, but my slicers has 52 settings, and I won't manually set this up for each setting.

Answer (score 1):

Closest to this out-of-the-box is using `Tile` under `Slicer settings` > `Options` > `Style`.

[image]

---

An alternative option that you may want to consider is using the custom visual from Microsoft called [Time Brush Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/PowerBIVisuals/WA104380798), available on AppSource. It does have increment buttons, but it also has a play/stop/pause buttons too.

[image]